# How to fake 404 in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I would like to set /directory/default.aspx to return 404 even though file and folder exist. How is this possible to do in IIS7 settings?

Update: I would like to do this in IIS Manager, not on code.

Comment: Best asked on ServerFault I'd suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no IIS setting for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try throwing an exception inside of your default.aspx:

```
throw new HttpException (404, "");
```

Comment: I would like to do this in IIS 7 settings.